# How to obtain the path of Desktop in gnome

Tags: linux, ubuntu, internationalization, gnome

I am using gnome/Ubuntu-10.10 in Chinese language and the desktop path is not "~/Desktop" but "~/XXXX" where XXXX stands for the Chinese translation of "Desktop". So, how to write code to obtain the proper path of desktop regardless of the system language? I noticed Qt SDK properly added a shortcut on the desktop so I guess there is a way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this question should be in SuperUser

Comment: "how to write code to obtain the proper path of desktop regardless of the system language?" - sounds like programming to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested yet, but try echo `echo ${XDG_DESKTOP_DIR:-$HOME/Desktop}`, this cmd maybe do the work.

Comment: That does not work for my localized desktop. dir=$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP) worked though

Answer (score 15):

One more way to do it:

```
dir=$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)
```

Comment: +1: works for me. FFire solution do not, as the XDG_DESKTOP_DIR was not defined

Answer (score 4):

The locations of the user directories are described in the [xdg-user-dirs](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs) specification. They provide some code [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-user-dirs/tree/xdg-user-dir-lookup.c) that you can copy, to look up the name of the desktop directory from within your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo ${XDG_DESKTOP_DIR:-$HOME/Desktop}
```

works fine on a local linux drive and also when the `/home/<user>` is mapped to an nfs drive.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Glib, you can do

```
const char *desktop_dir = g_get_user_special_dir (G_USER_DIRECTORY_DESKTOP);
```

This properly pays attention to the XDG environment variables and all that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is provided by [xdg-user-dirs specs](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/):

```
test -f ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/user-dirs.dirs && source ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/user-dirs.dirs
echo ${XDG_DESKTOP_DIR:-$HOME/Desktop}
echo ${XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR:-$HOME}
```